# Population density grid confusion

Tags: qgis, cost-path, population, utfgrid

I have a multi polygons data where red means most populated and white means less populated. I created a gridded population density (image on the right) out of them, but the result seems not quite make sense to me.

The reason I tried to do this is to combine this gridded population density data with multi points data of ambulance and road network. Eventually the data will be compiled using cost distance to create choropleth maps able to show the ambulance response time below 15 minutes, below 30 minutes and below 2 hours.

For the gridded population density data, I created it using styled heatmap (kernel density estimation from the plugin Density Analysis).

How can I make the gridded population density out of multi polygons of population density data, so it would be compatible enough to do cost distance analysis with road network and multi points of ambulance?

[image: left: multipolygons population density. right: gridded population density]